# как встроить нужные файлы в ехешник с++?

Tags: python, c++, exe, python-c-api

если я использую python/c api и выполняю какой либо код питона в с++ и все это преобразую в ехе то при запуске на другом пк появляются ошибки с dll и lib (то что их нету)

можно как то встроить в код с++ dll и lib файлы? или приклеить их к ехешнику?

пример кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    PyObject* pInt;
    const char* code = R""""(
print('hello world')

x = 28 * 32 / 4
print(x)
)"""";

    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString(code);

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Какой инструмент используете?

Comment: @Александр visual studio 2022

Comment: Там плагин или самостоятельно интегрируете питон в c++? Должно как-то настраиваться.

Comment: @Александр просто #include <Python.h>, мне кажется лучше в ехешник как то встраивать длл и либ файлы

Comment: Добавьте минимальный пример.

Comment: @Александр добавил

Comment: чего непонятного?

Comment: где это Вы видели чтобы dll были встроены в exe? всю жизнь люди копировали их (через установщик либо распаковщик) крайний случай `портабельная версия` в одном файле — но это же совсем другое

Comment: Гуглить фразу "статическая линковка". Как это делается в студии - не знаю.